# Android - how to get all the microphones that available?

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I want to give the user option to select which microphone he wants to use if there is more than one available.

How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sound is routed to available microphone automatically
>
> [more info here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19368/how-do-i-use-an-external-microphone-with-my-galaxy-nexus)

So i guess your best option is to use an intentChooser/dialog and let the user choose whether to use:

- Device's mic
- Wired headset mic
- Bluetooth headset mic

Then to check which source is connected and override system's auto routing.

1. [Check if wired headset is connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-into-an-android-device-or-not)
2. [Check and handle BT headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365260/detect-bluetooth-le-devices-in-android)
3. [Override sound to the desired source](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-output.html#HandleChanges)

**I didn't try any of this and i'm making some assumptions here!**

I hope this will point you out to the right direction.